# Could not connect to local.browserstack.com

Tags: intern, browserstack

I am try to do a functionnal test with browserstack. I got registered for free and I got my ids on browserstack website but when I do `./node_modules/.bin/intern-client config=tests/intern`, I got this message:

> Error: The tunnel reported: Could not connect to local.browserstack.com!

For more information about the message error, you can find in the following image: 
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8xKr.png][1]

Did you find any error like this one? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue reported [here](https://twitter.com/browserstack/status/729610910889746433). Downloading and replacing the binary from BrowserStack's [documentation](https://www.browserstack.com/local-testing#command-line) solved the issue. Could you try the same?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Nishant, I tried it unfortunately am still having the same error message :(. I don't understand the binairies issue.

Comment: Can you drop an email at support@browserstack.com with issue details? I am sure they will be able to help you.

Comment: Alrigth, I will do it. Thanks for your advice.@Nishant